# Ruby on Rails Project With Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner at ror. I am working on ubuntu.

I can create a new ror project with default database and there is no problem everything is okey.. but i want to create a project which have mysql database.

I use this command:

```
railse new myproject -d mysql
```

then, I set my mysql username and passwork on the database.myl file but when I try to start server I get this error message so It does not work:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/mehmet/Desktop/ror/neistersin/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mehmet/Desktop/ror/neistersin/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/mehmet/Desktop/ror/neistersin/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/mehmet/Desktop/ror/neistersin/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/mehmet/Desktop/ror/neistersin/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/mehmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: its probably a typo error in your database.yml file, can i see your database.yml file

Comment: yes, please show your database.yml content - but don't show us your real password and username

Comment: `test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: neistersin_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 123456
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

same for production and test

Comment: if that is your actual password, since that is a `Fixnum` type, convert it to a string type by simply doing '123456'

Comment: Done, but no changes?

Comment: are you seeing the same error?

Comment: yes same error again. I have changed my pass like '123456' but no changes..

Comment: thats okey, i solved the problem. thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In database.yml:

password: 123

should be

password: '123'

Note: '

This may not be the final solution, but 1st step towards approaching the problem.